# strategies for re-rendering component once based on multiple setStates() in a method chain?

Tags: reactjs

In my componentDidMount(), I need to call multiple specialized methods.  Each of these methods needs to call setState at the end of the method.  Is there a way to somehow defer this.setState from performing a component re-render until all of the methods have completed?  Here's some pseudocode which hopefully illustrates the general concept of what I have in mind:

```
componentDidMount(){
   this.setState.disableRerender();
   this.DoOneThing();
   this.DoSomethingElse();
   this.setState.enableRerender();
}

DoOneThing(){
   //this.setState(...)
}

DoSomethingElse(){
   //this.setState(...) 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `async/await` to do what you want and then `setState` with the results :

```
async componentDidMount(){
  
  const firstThing = await this.DoOneThing();
  const secondThing = await this.DoSomethingElse();
    
  this.setState({firstThing, secondThing})  
}

DoOneThing(){
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    // do the first thing
    res(5)
  })
}

DoSomethingElse(){
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    // do the other thing
    res(10)
  })
}
```